# Can I use a resistor to transfer voltage to current rather using transconductance amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, current-source, pll, transconductance-amplifier

The situation is I intend to transfer voltage to current to control a laser.
The voltage comes from an optical phase-locked loop (OPLL). It is changing over time, so the current transferred from this voltage changes as well.
From my point of view, I don't need a transconductance amplifier to form a constant current source. The current would variate with the voltage. So can I just use a resistor (or a potentiometer) to conduct this function?

If I use operational transconductance amplifiers to transfer voltage to current, the bandwidth might be a problem (I need high bandwidth to meet the phase margin of the whole OPLL system).

For transistors or MOSFET, it only works when voltage/current is over its threshold value. This characteristic might restrict my system.

I am curious about whether a resistor can be used to conduct the V-I conversion.

Comment: What does the manual for your laser controller say? BTW, "wanna" is "kinda" rude.

Comment: My controller's bandwidht is too narrow. I intend to transfer the voltage to the current and then add it with the bias current. Thanks for reminding me of my tone.

Comment: what are the max voltage and current values of your system ?

Comment: @Rahmany     The max current is 250mA and the max voltage is around 3V. But the current I want to get from the conversion is on the order of 1e-5A.

Comment: Seems worth a try...(simple solutions like this are attractive). Laser's temperature coefficient might be a problem - do you have a thermistor monitor at the laser? Your PLL should not be expected to track out temperature variations.

Comment: @glen-geek    Yes, My laser is held in a Butterfly package which has an intrinsic TEC.

Comment: You have to be careful with the resistor because a low resistor value can load your PLL circuit while a high resistor value will result in very low current.